# Usar uma função void como parâmetro de outra

Tags: c, funções, função-anônima

Vamos supor que eu precise que uma função execute até um certo ponto, chame outra , faça alguma ação, chame outra função, faça mais uma ação e termine de executar. Considerando que as funções chamadas recebem parâmetro mas não dão nenhum retorno para a primeira. Ex:

```
void comeco_fim(/*função 1*/, /*função 2*/){
  printf("começo");

  //executa a função 1

  printf("texto");

  //executa a função 2

  printf("fim");
}
```

Nesse caso, essa função serviria para não repetir a mesma sequência toda vez que eu precisasse dela, considerando que a ordem não muda, só mudam algumas partes no meio. Como fazer isso? Ou existe alguma forma mais correta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se eu entendi o que você quer, precisa declarar o parâmetro como um ponteira para uma função. Assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void comeco_fim(void (*func1)(void), void (*func2)(void)) {
    printf("começo");
    func1(); //está usando a variável para chamar a função
    printf("texto");
    func2();
    printf("fim");
}

void funcao1() {
    printf("funcao1");
}

void funcao2() {
    printf("funcao2");
}
int main(void) {
    comeco_fim(funcao1, funcao2); //está passando as funções definidas acima.
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/6ZE5N2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/sjszvsot-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/PointerVoid.c).

`void (*func1)(void)` indica que a variável `func1` será do tipo função que recebe nenhum parâmetro e retorna nada. Somente uma função com esta assinatura poderá ser passada como argumento para este parâmetro.

Comment: Perfeito. Querendo mais detalhes: [C pointer to functions](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex18.html)

Comment: Exatamente isso. Obrigado.