# Função int(*cmp)(void*,void*)

Tags: c, c++, funções, ponteiro, função-anônima

Sei que ela compara ponteiros e retorna um inteiro que determina se um menor que outro, no sentido da ordem. Mas, quando vou usá-la na `main()`, está dando algum erro. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Coloque seu código para que possamos ajudar. De preferência um [mcve].

Comment: int dllInsertAfterSpec(DlList *l, void *data, void *key, int (*cmp)(void *, void *));

Comment: Essa é a função. Quero saber como usá-la para comparar dados de um determinado tipo, na main

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la agora? Veja o [tour] para entender como funciona. Ajudaria muito indicar para todo mundo que a solução foi útil e satisfatória para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

A pergunta não dá muitos detalhes, mas isto é a assinatura de uma função que será recebida pelo parâmetro da função `dllInsertAfterSpec()`.

Isto é uma função anônima. Ou seja, é um ponteiro para um código em algum lugar. Este ponteiro é armazenado em alguma variável (ou pode passar direto como argumento). Pode passar uma função qualquer, escrita em qualquer linguagem, desde que ela tenha a assinatura de retornar um inteiro e passar como argumento para ela dois ponteiros genéricos. Obviamente que espera-se que o código use estes argumentos em uma comparação e retorne um número que indique como ela resultou. Só vendo a documentação para saber exatamente como escrever esta função. Um exemplo hipotético:

```
int FuncaoASerUsada(void *lhs, void *rhs) {
    unsigned int a = *((unsigned int*)lhs);
    unsigned int b = *((unsigned int*)rhs);
    return (b - a);
}
dllInsertAfterSpec(l, data, key, FuncaoASerUsada);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/FunctionDll.c).

Um [exemplo de uso de ponteiros para funções pode ser encontrado nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88304/101). Tem [mais exemplo nessa outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101).

[Pergunta útil para entender melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136361/101).