# O que são esses membros complexos dentro de uma struct?

Tags: c, struct, função-anônima

Tenho uma dúvida em uma `struct` referente às últimas linhas com `uchar` e `void` que é bem diferente do que conheço.

Por que muitos programadores usam *underline* nos nomes de `struct`s, variáveis etc...

```
struct WNMEnv_
{
    ObjectHeap *heap;
    int32 intfVersion;

    uchar (*IsInstanceOf) (WNMEnv *env, WObject obj, WClazz *clazz);

    void (*ThrowException) (WNMEnv *env, const char *name, const char *msg);
};
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Essas linhas são ponteiros para funções, eu já respondi com mais detalhes em [Usar uma função void como parâmetro de outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88304/101). O `void` e o `uchar` são tipos de retorno como ocorre em qualquer outra função. E o fato de estar dentro de uma `struct` não muda nada, apenas você tem variáveis para guardar o ponteiro para a função, mas ainda são funções normais, só o acesso é que será indireto. Tem um [outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/137773/101). E [mais um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136361/101).

Essa é uma forma de [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) para chamada de uma função, então você cria um ponteiro para um endereço onde está a função (o corpo da função estará em outro lugar), aí pode guardar em uma variável esse valor do ponteiro, neste caso a variável está dentro de uma `struct`. Se mudar o valor acessará uma função diferente, e isso é poderoso para dar flexibilidade e deixar decidir o que chamar em tempo de execução.

Na verdade este mecanismo usado desta forma é algo como o polimorfismo que talvez conheça da orientação a objeto. [É possível programar OO em C usando justamente esta capacidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53108/101). Quando usa uma linguagem nativamente OOP internamente é isto que ela faz, só que você não vê, em C você vê e manipula na mão.

Se não ficou claro, o segundo bloco de parênteses são os parâmetros da função. Então neste caso pegando o exemplo você pode em algum ponto do seu código dizer qual é a função a ser chamada colocando o endereço dela na variável `ThrowException` dentro do objeto que estiver manipulando que seja do tipo `WNMEnv_`. Portando quando cria o objeto você configura o que deve ser chamado. Em algum lugar a função chamada virá do que está em `ThrowException`, provavelmente esta chamada já está dentro da infraestrutura do que está usando, faz parte da implementação interna desta API, você só configura o que será executado.

Se conhece alguma outra linguagem mais abstrata pode comparar com [*lambda*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) ou [função anônima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13364/101). Internamente é assim que funciona, mesmo nessas linguagens. Também chamamos de [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101).

Para entender melhor seria interessante pegar um trecho de código que tenha o uso disto ou um exemplo de objeto criado e configurado para uso disto.

Isso é outra pergunta mas vamos lá, as pessoas usam `_` para evitar algum conflito de novos, em geral o time escolhe uma convenção que nomes com ele tem um significado especial, assim não mistura com outros nomes que podem precisar ser iguais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigada Maniero, só mais uma questão que fiquei em dúvida...
Dentro dessa struct, tem mais itens, um deles é esse:
char *(*GetStringChars) (WNMEnv *env, WObject str, int32 flags);
Aqui:  *(*GetStringChars)  quer dizer ponteiro para o ponteiro de GetStringChars?

Answer (score 0):

Só pra acrescentar: `struct WNMEnv_` isso não é um underline e sim um underscore. o uso fará muita diferença em documentos externos por exemplo ler e escrever em um arquivo do word em seu projeto.

O underscore fica do lado do "caractere_".

O underline fica embaixo do ["caractere"](https://www) (* alguém sabe sublinhar uma palavra aqui no stackoverflow? tive que improvisar rsrsrs)